# Scanner returning an error for no reason?

Tags: java, string, exception, input, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to do this line of code. I want it to take a String, if it is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 or 10 to parse it into a int and then check if it is between 0 and 9 (after a -1). The issue is right after the scanner happens I get an error no matter what I do...

```
public void guessEnter() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String guessXS;
    String guessYS;
    boolean pass1;
    boolean pass2;

    do{
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a value for the column!");
            guessXS = scan.nextLine();
            switch(guessXS){
                case "1": case "2": case "3": case "4": case "5": case "6": case "7": case "8": case "9":case "10":
                    System.out.println("TRUE");
                    pass1 = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("FALSE");
                    pass1 = false;
                    break;
            }
        }while(pass1 == false);
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a value for the row!");
            guessYS = scan.nextLine();
            switch(guessYS){
                case "1": case "2": case "3": case "4": case "5": case "6": case "7": case "8": case "9": case "10":
                    pass2 = true;
                    System.out.println("TRUE");
                    break;
                default:
                    pass2 = false;
                    System.out.println("FALSE");
                    break;
            }
        }while(pass2 == false);
        guessX = Integer.parseInt(guessXS) - 1;
        guessY = Integer.parseInt(guessYS) - 1;
    }while(guessX >= 0 && guessX <= 9 && guessY >= 0 && guessY <= 9);
}
```

Why this is happening is beyond me. I am fairly new to java and need this error sorted out.

The error is...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)

at shipLocation.xyInput(shipLocation.java:11)

at battleShipMain.main(battleShipMain.java:53)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What was the input string when it crashed?

Comment: Why not just use Integer.parseInt() with a try-catch block and *then* check the number range?

Comment: Why not just use Integer.parseInt() with a try-catch block and then check the number range? Because I want to make it a fall safe if its not entered as a int. ---- What was the input string when it crashed? I tried all of them, they all crash besides ints.

Comment: Have you changed the method's name? According to your stacktrace the error seems to be in a method named `xyInput()` and not in `guessEnter()`.

Comment: YES! Brilliant! That was it I was looking at the wrong Choose a column number println! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the question has already been answered (the error was in a different class) and the provided code caused no error you maybe want to improve your code a bit. To make it easier to read and understand in case you have to change it later.

You could for example wrap the input and validation part in a method:

```
private int readIntBetweenMinAndMax(String msg, int min, int max) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(msg);
    int userInput;
    do {
        try {
            userInput = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Please enter a valid integer");
            continue;
        }
        if (userInput > max || userInput < min) {
            System.err.println("Please enter a integer between " + min + " and " + max);
            continue;
        }
        return userInput;
    } while (true);
}
```

The method above prints a provided string `msg` and then reads in an integer. It checks if the user input is an integer and if it's **greater or equals** than `min` and **less or equals** than `max`. In case one of the three conditions fails the method will print an error message and prompt the user for a new input until its correct.
*Note: You could of course also include the "TRUE" and "FALSE" outputs if you want*

So you would only have to call the method two times in your `guessEnter` method:

```
public void guessEnter() {
    guessX = readIntBetweenMinAndMax("Enter a value for the column!", 1, 10) - 1;
    guessY = readIntBetweenMinAndMax("Enter a value for the row!", 1, 10) - 1;
}
```

This would accept one, ten and any number between the them. And subtract one as you did in your code.

As a said, it's just a **suggestion** and I'm not sure if a got everything form your code right but I hope it helps (: